# Playa in a matrix column P&T example

Tags: matrix, playa

I've been trying to use the sample code from Pixel and Tonic for accessing playa data in a matrix field (ee2.10, playa 4.5.2, matrix 2.6.1). They provide a very clear example which I cannot get to work. Here's their example which is exactly what I want to accomplish:

---

```
{my_matrix_field var_prefix="spkr"}
    {spkr:favorite_bands} {!-- a Playa column --}
        {albums var_prefix="albm"} {!-- a Matrix field inside the band channel --}
            {spkr:row_count}.{albm:row_count} - {albm:album_title}
        {/albums}
    {/spkr:favorite_bands}
{/my_matrix_field}
```

---

However, using this as I guide I get no results. I've had to modify the above code and instead of accessing the playa column as suggested above, I've had to resort to a playa children tag which seem less efficient. Here's my code using the above as a guide that results in no output from the playa column. I'm wondering if other's have tried using P&Ts example with or without success.

---

```
{neighborhood_plans var_prefix="npd" search:neighborhood_plan_availability="not hide"}{!-- Matrix field in neighborhood channel --}
    {neighborhood_plan var_prefix="pd"}{!-- Playa column in matrix field in neighborhood channel --}
        {pd:title}
    {/neighborhood_plan}
{/neighborhood_plans}
```

---

Comment: Have you tried a bare bones template which outputs only very simple data (like titles) following their example code? Can you post that code here? It will be much easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: I added the bare bones code to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like our Playa field tag (`{neighborhood_plan}`) is missing the prefix - it needs that since it's inside of your prefixed Matrix field:

```
{neighborhood_plans var_prefix="npd" search:neighborhood_plan_availability="not hide"}{!-- Matrix field in neighborhood channel --}
    {npd:neighborhood_plan var_prefix="pd"}{!-- Playa column in matrix field in neighborhood channel --}
        {pd:title}
    {/npd:neighborhood_plan}
{/neighborhood_plans}
```

Comment: That was it. Well, it was that and the status parameter in combination. At one time I had the prefix in there, but without the status, and I wrongly thought the problem was related to the playa tag. Thanks for setting me straight.